# Icons in action bar just dissapeared

Tags: android, android-actionbar

so I've been adding a button to action bar, next to the tree dots.
So first, naturally without declaring "Show as action" there is tree dots and inside it is the button and a default setting button.

When I declared "Show as action" as always, it worked.

But upon making a "onOptionsItemSelected" both tree dots and the button disappeared.

And now I can't get either back, even if I delete everything I added and did since, I still can't get the tree dots back.

Here's the code, sorry I forgot it:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/item1" 
    android:orderInCategory="99"
    android:title="@string/addVal"
    android:checkable="true" android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

So that's the menu coding.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.item1:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddBox.class);
            startActivity(i);

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

And this is the boolean.

Comment: Post your code, please!

Comment: What does this mean? But upon making a "onOptionsItemSelected" both tree dots and the button disappeared.

Comment: sorry I got the code in

Answer (score 0):

You should return from the first option in your switch, otherwise the second default option will be executed:

```
switch (item.getItemId()){ 
case R.id.item1: 
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddBox.class); 
    startActivity(i);
    return true;
default: 
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Comment: I still didn't get the action bar icons back